# User in keystore cannot have permission in .policy

Tags: java, security, keystore, content-security-policy, policy

I need to give full access to an user in a .policy file

```
keystore "file:myKeystore.keystore";

grant signedBy "myUser" {
     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
     permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
```

And i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.name" "read")
```

The execution is done like that :

```
$ keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias myTestKey -keystore myKeystore.keystore -validity 360
$ jarsigner -keystore myKeystore.keystore -verbose security-test.jar myTestKey
$ java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=./custom-policy.policy -jar security-test.jar testfile.txt
```

I tried to give the full path but its also not working. I also tried to remove the user to see if the .policy if working, and yes it is :

```
   grant  {
         permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
         permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your custom-policy.policy the password to use your keystore.

The first two lines of your policy file must be like the following.

```
keystore "file:PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE";
keystorePasswordURL "file:PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_FILE";
```

For the password file you can just do this :

```
echo "KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" > KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_FILE
```

Remember that this is not suitable for a production environment, but maybe it can do the trick in the context of your usage.

Also, the alias used by the signedBy directive must be myTestKey here, not myUser.